# How many WSDL specification extensibility elements are allowed in a WSDL document

Tags: xml, wsdl

The wsdl specification can be extended using extensibility elements, such as SOAP.

These extensibility elements appear around the bindings, operations and port sections of the wsdl document (http://www.w3.org/TR/wsdl - 2.1 WSDL Document Structure)

I am trying to parse a wsdl document, and the specification doesn't seem to detail how many extensibility elements may appear in a given place. E.g. for a given binding, can multiple extensions be applied such as the example below?

```
<binding name="StockQuoteSoapBinding" type="defs:StockQuotePortType">
  <soap:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
  <foo:otherextension foo="bar"/>
```

Whilst no limit on the number of extensions is defined, no examples exist that demonstrate the use of multiple extensions either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [XML Schema for WSDL](http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/) indicates that an unbounded number of elements (as long as they belong to a namespace outside of WSDL) can be used in one of the elements defined to be extensible:

```
<xs:complexType name="tExtensibleDocumented" abstract="true">
    <xs:complexContent>
        <xs:extension base="wsdl:tDocumented">
            <xs:annotation><xs:documentation>
            This type is extended by component types to allow elements from other namespaces to be added.
            </xs:documentation></xs:annotation>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:any namespace="##other" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" processContents="lax"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:extension>
    </xs:complexContent>
</xs:complexType>
```